# How to display and open installed applications on local machine using asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications

**How to display and open installed applications on local machine using asp.net web application**

**I want to show the list with a dropdown menu and when I click on any application that application should open.**

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to do some more research and post a specific question if you encounter a specific issue.

Comment: Can you share what's the exact problem you are trying to solve? Your asp.net web application which is running on web server can not access to the client computer and get the application installation details.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, the answer is "You can't."

Reason: Your web application is sand boxed due to security reasons.
Think of it like this: You don't want Facebook to find all your installed applications to figure out what ads to show you.  You don't want any malicous site to figure out which applications you have installed to exploit a security error in application X.